# Bash - aliasing unalias

Tags: linux, bash, shell, alias

I know that using **alias** command in bash can define custom functions in bash, and can even overwrite inbuilt functions (for e.g. **alias sudo="help"** works). **Unalias -a** can tidy up the mess made with alias command, but **unalias** can also be aliased (I have run **alias unalias="unalias"** command successfully, so I guess it works for other commands too - I did not want to mess up the os since it was a public computer).
My question is that if I alias the unalias to something else, and then the alias too, can I reset the commands if they are themselves not usable? What happens if I aliased sudo too? 
For e.g. if I wanted to be a troll and run this command on the machine of a friend of mine

```
    alias sudo="clear" && alias unalias="clear" && alias alias="clear"
```

all these commands will be unusable, so I'm sure it will be a hard time to restore the functionality of sudo. Is it possible without reinstalling the OS?

(I can think about using ctrl+alt+f1 that switches to a terminal, but I do not know if the aliased stuff is aliased there too. What if I do the same thing there?)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A commonly used technique to prefix a command with a backslash i.e. `\` to make sure to avoid any aliases and run it from system default path:

Example:

```
$> alias ps=date
$> ps
Wed Feb 18 12:33:17 EST 2015
$> \ps
 PID TTY           TIME CMD
 615 ttys000    0:00.66 -bash
 621 ttys001    0:07.36 -bash
 913 ttys002    0:01.19 -bash
```

As you can use running `\ps` runs system default `/bin/ps` while running `ps` runs the aliased command `date`.

Comment: Is that a documented feature or a trick that just happens to work?

Comment: I have been using for many years but I am sure there will be some documentation about it. I will try to find out some documentation for this.

Comment: [A reference](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/39291/run-a-command-that-is-shadowed-by-an-alias)

Comment: "\" is simply telling shell that the following character (`l`) should be treated as-is, so shell won't apply alias on it.

Answer (score 2):

To expand [anubhava's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28589918/bash-aliasing-unalias/28590308#28590087): you can also use single or double quotes:

```
$ alias ps=date
$ ps
Wed Feb 18 12:33:17 EST 2015
$ "ps"
 PID TTY           TIME CMD
 615 ttys000    0:00.66 -bash
 621 ttys001    0:07.36 -bash
 913 ttys002    0:01.19 -bash
```

In general, any expression that evaluates to *ps* will be unaliased.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to execute a binary and not an alias with the same name just type the whole path to the binary:

```
/usr/bin/sudo <cmd>
```

Having that aliases are only available in interactive shells and not in shell scripts the also won't break anything else.

---

To "remove" that aliases simply remove them from your `.bashrc` and start a new shell.

Comment: @EtanReisner Yeah, anubhava already answered that and I appreciated that. Thank you too. Knowing this it is not necessary to type the whole path  anymore. however will keep this answer as an alternative...

Comment: A whole path doesn't work for shell built-ins so yeah, the alternatives are useful if you alias those.